In VSCode, is there a way to have a conditional breakpoint not stop at the breakpoint, like a conditional/action breakpoint in Visual Studio?
I want to log a variable's value at a breakpoint, conditionally, and not stop at the breakpoint.
In VSCode, Logpoints don't stop at the breakpoint, but can't be conditional. Conditional Breakpoints can't not stop code execution at the breakpoint.
I could just do this with an if statement and print statement, but it would be nice if there was a way to do this with the debugger.

I've not tried this, but can you just slap a ternary or something in the log expression to be empty if the condition isn't met? It may still log an empty string, but that would at least be a minor improvement
